# Bash sed string substitution error

Tags: regex, json, bash, sed, git-bash

I have a json file, which contains the following for example:

```
"images": [
    ".images/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg", 
    ".images/phones/motorola-xoom.1.jpg", 
    ".images/phones/motorola-xoom.2.jpg"
],
```

Using git bash on Windows and sed I am trying to substitute `.images` with `./images`.
I thought of using `sed -i 's/.images/.\/images/g' filename.json` however when doing that sed selects and replaces the first instance of "images" as well. Why is that and how should I modify file my sed command?
Thx

Comment: `.` is a regex metacharacter, you need to escape it in the pattern string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the dot `.`. As `.` means "anything", you have to escape it to make it mean just `.`:

```
$ sed 's/\.images/.\/images/g' file
"images": [
    "./images/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg", 
    "./images/phones/motorola-xoom.1.jpg", 
    "./images/phones/motorola-xoom.2.jpg"
],
```